# Dichotomous search algorithm in numeric optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If we assume that $\phi$ is convex and continuous in $[a,b]$, it is obvius that, in this interval, $\phi$ has a minimizer. The goal is know what point is it.

The main idea of Dichotomous search is reduce the size of the interval what is the minimizer evaluating $\phi$ into two points, $\overline{a}, \overline{b} \in (a,b) : \overline{a} < \overline{b} $.

For this, the algorithm uses the fact that if $\phi(\overline{a}) < \phi(\overline{b})$, the minium of $\phi$ in $[a,b]$ is contained in the interval $[a,\overline{b}]$. And $\phi(\overline{a}) \geq \phi(\overline{b})$, the minium of $\phi$ in $[a,b]$ is contained in the interval $[\overline{a},b]$

Therefore, the Dichotomous algorithm computes the midpoint of the interval (step-by-step), $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and, then moves slightly to either side of the midpoint to compute two test points: $\frac{a+b}{2} \pm \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is a very small number.

**Why need to move slightly to either side of the midpoint?**

Comment: It is not obvious at all that $\phi$ has a minimizer; is $\phi$ perhaps assumed to be continuous so we can apply the Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Correct. I must add continuity constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you need to evaluate the function at two points, $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$. The closer those $\bar{b}$ is to $a$, and the closer $\bar{a}$ is to $b$, the further you can shrink the interval, so you want $\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ to be close to each other.

Comment: But, why I need to evaluate the function into $\frac{a+b}{2} \pm \varepsilon$ and not in $\frac{a+b}{2}$?

Comment: @J.García you have to pick two distinct points. You can pick $(a+b)/2$ and $(a+b)/2+\varepsilon$ if you like. Or $(a+b)/2-\varepsilon$ and $(a+b)/2$. Your teacher or book selected $(a+b)/2-\varepsilon$ and $(a+b)/2+\varepsilon$, but you do not have to.

Comment: But, why I must pick two disctinct points? If I evaluate only in one point, $f(point)$, why can't do dichotomous search?

Comment: @J.García because your algorithm compares $f(\bar{a})$ with $f(\bar{b})$. The current algorithm needs two points because if you only know the function value at the midpoint you do not know in which subinterval to continue the search. You could use a *different* algorithm based on the derivative at the midpoint that only needs one derivative evaluation.